# Better display limits in latex

Tags: latex

Is there any code in latex so that the limits or the indices of sums can be better displayed?

When I'm writing "n goes to infinity" it is written right and down the limit , not above it.

Comment: You may find this helpful: [Show inline math as if it were display math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32824/show-inline-math-as-if-it-were-display-math)

Comment: (This is best asked on [tex.se].)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are using inline math mode (the formula is between dollar signs). If you use a proper formatted math environment, like displaymath or equation, the limits will format nicer. E.g.

```
\begin{displaymath}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} q^{-n}=\frac{1}{1-q}
\end{displaymath}
```

Inline math uses that wierd position for the indices in order to avoid stretching the spacing between subsequent lines. Nevertheless, you can override it, if you really want to do so, by the \limits command.
This post covers it in detail:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32824/show-inline-math-as-if-it-were-display-math

Comment: Thank you a lot.Indeed, I was just writing math between $$,.